# how to make test over an eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

//The value of etat_demande needs to be En attente so i can be deleted else it shows an error message

```
public function destroy($id){
    $etat_demande = DB::table('demandes')
    ->where('etat_demande','LIKE','%En attente%')
    ->select('demandes.etat_demande')
    ->first();
    if($etat_demande == 'En attente'){
        demande::destroy($id);
        return redirect('demandeur/demandes')->with('succes','Demande annuler !');
    }else{
        return redirect('demandeur/demandes')->with('error','La demande a deja été valider !');
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no question here, or any information as to let us know what you need help with. Furthermore you always get the `first()` item of `demandes` table? It's unclear what you want.. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i am trying to test over the value of etat_demande if it is equal to En attente then the item can be deleted

Comment: if you want to delete value if it is equal to En attente than instead of using *first()* use *delete()*. it will delete value if it match

Comment: if i use delete instead of get() or first() it will delete all the colums that has the value En attente in it

Comment: @Zen3x You provide the method with an id, they should not be duplicated therefore you can delete only 1 item

Comment: that's exactly what i did but it seems that the if() statement doesn't work